# Best subsample in the Maxmin distance sense

Tags: algorithm, distance, mathematical-optimization

I have a set of N points in a D-dimensional metric space. I want to select K of them in such a way that the smallest distance between any two points in the subset is the largest.

For instance, with N=4 and K=3 in 3D Euclidean space, the solution is the face of the tetrahedron having the longest short side.

Is there a classical way to achieve that ? Can it be solved exactly in polynomial time ?

I have googled as much as I could, but I have not figured out yet how to call this problem.

In my case N=50, K=10 and D=300 typically.

Clarification:

A brute force approach would be to try every combination of K points among the N and determine the closest pair in every subset. The solution is given by the subset that yields the longest pair.

Done the trivial way, an O(K^2) process, to be repeated N! / K!(N-K)! times.

Hum, 10^2 50! / 10! 40! = 1027227817000

Comment: Sounds as you can do that building a graph with the distances between points and then running a modified version of a Kruskal algorithm to build max-spanning tree

Comment: A max-spanning tree could be V-shaped with long links between nodes but with two nodes not joined by a link very close together. I can think of some obvious hill-climbing and greedy algorithms for this (scan through the data and repeatedly see if swapping the new point with one of the points held so far would improve things) but they won't give certain optima

Comment: Assuming I have built the maximum spanning tree on the N points. How do I prune the tree to get my K subsample ? In what way does the spanning tree get me closer to the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might find papers on unit disk graphs informative but discouraging. For instance, http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.84.3113&rep=rep1&type=pdf states that the maximum independent set problem on unit disk graphs in NP-complete, even if the disk representation is known. A unit disk graph is the graph you get by placing points in the plane and forming links between every pair of points at most a unit distance apart.

So I think that if you could solve your problem in polynomial time you could run it on a unit disk graph for different values of K until you find a value at which the smallest distance between two chosen points was just over one, and I think this would be a maximum independent set on the unit disk graph, which would be solving an NP-complete problem in polynomial time.

(Just about to jump on a bicycle so this is a bit rushed, but searching for papers on unit disk graphs might at least turn up some useful search terms)

Here's an attempt to explain it piece by piece:

Here is another attempt to relate the two problems.

For maximum independent set see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_independent_set#Finding_maximum_independent_sets. A decision problem version of this is "Are there K vertices in this graph such that no two are joined by an edge?" If you can solve this you can certainly find a maximum independent set by finding the largest K by asking this question for different K and then finding the K nodes by asking the question on versions of the graph with one or more nodes deleted.

I state without proof that finding the maximum independent set in a unit disk graph is NP-complete. Another reference for this is http://web.sau.edu/lilliskevinm/wirelessbib/ClarkColbournJohnson.pdf.

A decision version of your problem is "Do there exist K points with distance at least D between any two points?" Again, you can solve this in polynomial time iff you can solve your original problem in polynomial time - play around until you find the largest D that gives answer yes, and then delete points and see what happens.

A unit disk graph has an edge exactly when the distance between two points is 1 or less. So if you could solve the decision version of your original problem you could solve the decision version of the unit disk graph problem just by setting D = 1 and solving your problem.

So I think I have constructed a series of links showing that if you could solve your problem you could solve an NP-complete problem by turning it into your problem, which causes me to think that your problem is hard.

Comment: That's a quite interesting approach, indeed a bit discouraging. If find it mentally difficult to check if your argument is correct, though :(

Comment: I've tried adding a section going over my argument step by step